# How to insert image as blob in DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2, base64, blob

while inserting a base64 encoded image (now string) to DB2 the following error is given:

> Illegal conversion: can not convert from "java.lang.String" to "java.sql.Blob" ERRORCODE=-4474, SQLSTATE=null

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a base64 decoder:

- Java 1.8 now has one built in
- Java 1.7 and earlier, you can use the
  Apache CODEC, or the XML data converter.

`byte[] imageBlob = Decoder.decode(imageBase64String);`
`preparedStatement.setBytes(blobColumn,imageBlob);`

If you want to save the Base64 encoded string, then just use
`preparedStatement.setBytes(blobColumn,imageBase64String.getBytes());`